# Sending Http POST Request through Rest API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, post, parse-platform

I am trying to send an Http post request to parse.com server through Rest API keys. Not sure if I am doing it right as below. The following is my whole script and makes a button which should trigger the post request in a simple HTML page.

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="doFunction();" />
<script>

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/english";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "VnxVYV8ndyp6hE7FlPxBdXdhxTCmxX1111111");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key","6QzJ0FRSPIhXbEziFFPs7JvH1l11111111");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
var parameters = {
    "ephrase": "english",
    "pphrase": "farsi",
     "nvote": 0,
    "yvote": 0
};
// Neither was accepted when I set with parameters="username=myname"+"&password=mypass" as the server may not accept that

function doFunction() {
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}

</script>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I get no error. There is just nothing happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.send(parameters);
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

That needs to be a string, but it is an object, so will be converted to the string: `"[object Object]"`.

You need to convert the data to the proper encoding first.

You've said:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

so you can use `JSON.stringify(parameters)` for that.

Comment: im also trying to do the very same thing and the parameter that I am passing is string, even though getting `XHR failed loading: POST`

Comment: stringifying the data means a content type of `text/plain` needs to be sent, `application/json` suggest the body is a json object

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). The return value of `JSON.stringify` is a string of *JSON* not a string of *plain* text.

Comment: which is formatted/written out as `"{propName: 'someValue'}"` which is a string

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — It would be `'{"propName": "someValue"}'` which is a string **of JSON**.

Comment: by bad of the wrong quotes, but my point stands, a JSON object isnt quoted on the outside `{...}` whereas a JSON string is `'{...}'`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — The quotes on the outside (in this context, along with some others such as `console.log`) are just a convention to indicate that it is a string. `JSON.stringify` does not add the quotes to the outside to the actual data.

Comment: if you try to read a property from a `JSON.stringify()` it would be undefined as only string methods are available

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — That's because it is a string of JSON (suitable for sending over HTTP) and not a JavaScript object! This is why `JSON.parse` exists: So JSON can be converted into a JavaScript data structure.

Comment: your first part of that comment agrees with me... a string of JSON isnt the same as a JSON object, a JSON object isnt a string but a JSON string is a stringed form of a JSON object!

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — No. You are thinking of JavaScript objects.

Comment: JSON literally stands for `JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — That's because the syntax was inspired by JavaScript, not because it is part of JavaScript.

Comment: I never claimed it to be part of JavaScript, only that a JSON Object is not surrounded by quotes, a JSON string is

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — JSON is a text based format. If you want JSON in JavaScript then it will be expressed in the form of a JavaScript string. If you want it in JavaScirpt source code then it will be expressed as a JavaScript string literal. In the latter case will it have quotes around it.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — W3Schools is **awful**. Never believe them.

Comment: yet its based on w3c, just a more user friendly way of viewing the *standards*

Comment: No it isn't. W3Schools get a lot of reflected glory by naming themselves so they *sound* like part of the W3C. They are, however, just a terrible advertising riddled vendor of very low-quality resources. Neither JSON nor JavaScript are W3C standards anyway (they are IETF and ECMA standards respectively).

Comment: Yes it is, nothing that ive ever found on w3schools has been low quality. and again, i never claimed JSON to be a w3c standard

Comment: The page you linked to is very low-quality.  The first section is *almost* correct. Then everything after "Accessing Object Values" is suddenly talking about JavaScript instead of JSON (except it calls JSON "JavaScript").

Comment: No, it isnt talking about javascript nor is it low quality

Comment: Feel free to paste `myObj = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };` into https://jsonlint.com - it's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: All it does is drop each key pair onto a new line, which makes it easier to read

Comment: @mast3rd3mon — And displays a big red box underneath which starts "Error: Parse error on line 1"

Comment: ah, my mouse was in the input box so it didnt let me scroll, your sample errors as you have a javascript variable assign in the front, using `{ "test": 543 }` works but `'{ "test": 543 }'` doesnt

Comment: That's because it is JavaScript and not JSON!

Comment: To put it another way. Compare "I went to the hotel" with "Ich ging zum hotel". One sentence is English the other is German. Both include the word *hotel*, but in context that word is either English or German. It isn't a German word in an English sentence. `{}` is the syntax for an object literal in JavaScript, it is also the syntax for an object in JSON. If you put it in JavaScript, then it isn't JSON. You could, in JS, say `var myJSON = "{}"` which would be like saying `In my German lesson, I learned the phrase "Ich ging zum hotel"`